# WHERE NOT Query in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am querying into database using the following code and it is working fine

```
<?php query_posts( 

'post_type=gallery&posts_per_page='.$gnum.'&paged='.$paged.'&orderby=title&order=ASC'

 ); ?>
```

Could you please tell me how to add WHERE NOT with the above query.

(`WHERE ID != '400' AND ID!='401'`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In wordpress query post add argument `post__not_in`.

```
'post__not_in' => array(400, 401)

$args = array(
     'post_type' => 'gallery',
     'posts_per_page' => $gnum,
     'post__not_in' => array(400, 401),
     'paged' => $paged,
     'orderby' => 'title',
     'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

So your query post will be like,

```
query_posts($args);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your code but it says `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in C:\...`

Comment: @black_belt - try with my updated answer. Just take all argument in one array `$args` which will remove confusion.

Comment: If you don't mind may I ask you what to change in the above code if I want to show only `400` and `401`. THanks

Comment: I think just try replacing `post__not_in` by `post__in`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$args = array(
           'post_type' => 'gallery',
           'posts_per_page' => $gnum,
           'paged' => $paged,
           'orderby' => 'title',
           'order' => 'ASC',
           'post__not_in' => array(6,2,8) 
        );
query_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to include this with my query.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php query_posts( 

'post_type=gallery&posts_per_page='.$gnum.'&paged='.$paged.'&orderby=title&ID='-400,-401'&order=ASC'

 ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..But its Not working.. :( Showing Parse Error